# Rsyslog running but not monitoring specified ImFile

Tags: rsyslog

Rsyslog is running but is unable to track changes on an specified imfile.

```
$InputFileName /opt/liferay/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp16/test.log
$InputFileTag test-log-ing
$InputFileStateFile stat-test-log-ing
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollInterval 10
```

modfile imfile is loaded as so.

```
$ModLoad imfile
```

`lsof|grep rsyslog` - does not have rsyslog monitoring the file. I am only trying to monitor 1 file.

'logger test' sends a message to /var/log/messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your question with the version of rsyslog (and if you can, the OS), and confirm where you put the config for imfile? It might also help answer your question if you could provide the timestamps on the file you are trying to monitor - if that's not possible, how often is data written to that file?

Comment: Rsyslog- "5.8.10" and RHEL 6.4. Yes i can confirm the location of the config for imfile I also put it straight into the rsyslog.conf file. Data is put into the file whenever the application runs. I've manually put data into the log. The issue here is that the imfile file monitor isnt there via rsyslog.